# How to load a package?

Tags: packages, files-and-directories, gitlink

I am new to github and loading github pacakges on Mathematica. I'm trying to follow examples from here. I used the PacletDirectoryLoad to load the packge from github but I get the following error. Any guidance on how to proceed?

```
PacletDirectoryLoad[~"https://github.com/aethomsen/rgbeta]
```

Erorr `"Directory \ \!\(\"\\\\\\\\ewa-ecvfp1\\\\ts_redirect_22-23$\\\\pgibson\\\\My \ Documents\\\\~https:\\\\github.com\\\\aethomsen\\\\rgbeta\"\) not \ found"`

Comment: There are clear installation instructions for the package that you quote. If you want to install this specific package, why don't you follow those instructions? There is no general package installation method in Mathematica. The procedure depends on the specific package, and how it's distributed. Note that this package is not distributed as a paclet, so you cannot use paclet handling functions. Furthermore, packages can't in general be loaded directly from GitHub. To access the contents of a GitHub repo, you can clone it and access it on your hard drive.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on misunderstandings, and therefore cannot be answered.

Comment: When you open code in github, there is an ability to see raw, txt coded page, instead of html5.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to load a package from GitHub into Mathematica. To do this, you can use the [`PacletInstall`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PacletInstall.html) function in Mathematica.

Here is an example of how to use `PacletInstall` to install a package from GitHub:

```
PacletInstall[ "https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/v1.0.0/Package.paclet"]
```

Replace "https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/v1.0.0/Package.paclet" with the URL of the .paclet file for the package you want to install.

Alternatively, if you have cloned the package repository to your local machine, you can use the `PacletInstall` function with the file path to the .paclet file:

```
PacletInstall["C:\\Path\\To\\Package.paclet"]
```

Once the package is installed, you can use the `Needs` function to load the package into your Mathematica session:

```
Needs["Package`"]
```

If you want to use [`PacletDirectoryLoad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PacletDirectoryLoad.html) to load a package from a local directory, you can use the following syntax:

```
PacletDirectoryLoad /@ FileNames["*.paclet", "C:\\Path\\To\\Paclets\\Directory"]
```

This will load all .paclet files in the specified directory. Note that the `PacletDirectoryLoad` function only works with local directories, and cannot be used to load paclets from a remote location such as GitHub.

If you have cloned the package repository to your local machine and want to use `PacletDirectoryLoad` to load the package, you can navigate to the directory where the .paclet file is located and use the above syntax to load it.

Comment: You write, "It looks like you are trying to load a package from GitHub into Mathematica. To do this, you can use the PacletInstall function in Mathematica."  This is highly misleading to novice users and simply not true in general. The fact that a package is published on GitHub does not imply that a paclet file was also made available. It is certainly not true for the package that OP asked about.

Comment: Furthermore, `PacletDirectoryLoad` does not _load_ `.paclet` files. Paclet files are archives (they are literally zip files) that serve as a distribution format for packages. They can be _installed_ (not _loaded_) with `PacletInstall`. `PacletDirectoryLoad` is a function used during package development. It makes a _not yet packed_ paclet available from a directory without having to install it first.

Comment: For transparency, I downvoted this answer because it contains incorrect information.

Comment: FYI, There's no .paclet in releases in this case but if it was one could use `ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"][ "aethomsen", "rgbeta" ]` instead of looking for the correct url.